# Send email through Google Scripts from Slack Webhook

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, slack

Using Slack, and trying to set up an Outgoing Webhook to send an email when a user types in a certain keyword. Slack sends a POST in the following format:

```
token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
team_id=T0001
team_domain=example
channel_id=C2147483705
channel_name=test
timestamp=1355517523.000005
user_id=U2147483697
user_name=Steve
text=atsk: ticket#; ticket details
trigger_word=atsk:
```

It sends this POST to a URL that is set up with this Google script:

```
function autoMail(sendmail) {
  var params = sendmail.parameters;

  if (params.token == "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") {
    var textRaw = String(params.text).replace(/^\s*atsk\s*:*\s*/gi,'');
    var text = textRaw.split(/\s*;\s*/g);
    var email = "example@gmail.com";
    var subject = text[0];
    var message = text + "Ticket created by Autoslack Bot";
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Which is published as a Web App and set to run as 'Anyone, even anonymous' and been granted permission to use my Google Email.

So if someone types 'atsk: T12345678; User has an issue.' it should send an email to 'example@gmail.com' with the subject 'T12345678' and the message 'T12345678; User has an issue. Ticket created by Autoslack Bot'

I thought this was set up correctly, but I cannot get an email to send to the specified address. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Does the call to your Google script go through at all? Please add more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a test function to check the Apps script part on its own like this :

```
function testAutoMail() {
  var parameters={};
  parameters['text']='atsk: T12345678; User has an issue.';
  parameters['token']="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var arg = {};
  arg['parameters']=parameters;
  autoMail(arg);
}

function autoMail(sendmail) {
  var params = sendmail.parameters;

  if (params.token == "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") {
    var textRaw = String(params.text).replace(/^\s*atsk\s*:*\s*/gi,'');
    var text = textRaw.split(/\s*;\s*/g);
    var email = "example@gmail.com";
    var subject = text[0];
    var message = text + "Ticket created by Autoslack Bot";
    Logger.log('MailApp.sendEmail('+email+', '+subject+', '+message+')');

  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

And look at the Logger to see if it works.